# Delay loading data from DB using AngularJS service

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, angularjs

Im trying to read data from database using AngularJS and Ajax call with PHP.
My goal is to create an editable form, that has pre-loaded data.
The data is loaded perfectly as planned, But loaded with some annoying delay (~1s).
I am not sure what causes the view to load the data from the database in such a delay, therefore I would like to eliminate any chance of bad coding. maybe my code is all right, but the issue is the local server im using?
does it have anything with the $http.get ?

for now, Im doing a "loading" trick (using ng-show) that loads the form inputs only when the data is fully loaded. obviously I would prefer avoiding it.

any suggestions would be appreciated.

this is my controller:

```
app.controller('mainController', ['$scope',  '$http',
    function ($scope,$http){
        getMyData();

        $scope.saveBanner = function(){
            $http.post("includes/updateBanner.php",{"clickURL":$scope.clickURL,"priceColor":$scope.price_color_picker,"titleColor" : $scope.title_color_picker,"logoURL":$scope.logoURL}).success(function(data){
                getMyData();
            });
        };
        function getMyData(){
            $http.get("includes/getDetails.php").success(function(data){
                $scope.price_color_picker = data[0].priceColor;
                $scope.title_color_picker = data[0].titleColor;
                $scope.clickURL = data[0].clickUrl;
                $scope.logoURL = data[0].logoUrl;
                $scope.loaded = "true";
            });

        };

}]);
```

and this is the php file that returns the data in JSON to angular

```
<?php 
/*
 * includes/getDetails.php
 *
 * simple db handling file. returns db data using JSON format
 * 
 */

include("../includes/constants.php");
require_once '../classes/db.php'; // The DB class


$query="SELECT * FROM bannerData";
$dbObj = new db;
$dbObj -> db_connect();
$result = $dbObj->db_query($query);

$arr = array();
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $arr[] = $row;  
    }
}
$dbObj->db_disconnect();
# JSON-encode the response
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code. How many records are in bannerData? I noticed there is no filter on it.

Comment: only a 1 record. this is a very simple app, and the db is simple as well and only holds 4 parameters.